# In R, what does parentheses followed by parentheses mean

Tags: r

The syntax for using `scales::label_percent()` in a mutate function is unusual because it uses double parentheses:

`label_percent()(an_equation_goes_here)`

I don't think I have seen `()()` syntax in R before and I don't know how to look it up because I don't know what it is called.  I tried `` ?`()()` `` and `` ??`()()` `` and neither helped.  What is double parentheses syntax called?  Can someone recommend a place to read about it?

Here is an example for context:

```r
library(tidyverse)
members <- 
  read_csv(
    paste0(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/", 
      "master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv"
    ), 
    show_col_types = FALSE)


members %>%
  count(success, died) %>%
  group_by(success) %>%
  # old syntax:
  # mutate(percent = scales::percent(n / sum(n))) 
  # new syntax:
  mutate(percent = scales::label_percent()(n / sum(n))) 
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   success [2]
#>   success died      n percent
#>   <lgl>   <lgl> <int> <chr>  
#> 1 FALSE   FALSE 46452 98%    
#> 2 FALSE   TRUE    868 2%     
#> 3 TRUE    FALSE 28961 99%    
#> 4 TRUE    TRUE    238 1%
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: In addition to @r2evans’ excellent answer, you may find the [chapter on function factories](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html) in *Advanced R* interesting.

Comment: As always,  get thee a copy of "The R Inferno"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most functions return a value, whether something atomic (numeric, integer, character), list-like (including `data.frame`), or something more complex. For those, the single set of `()`s (as you recognize) are for the one call.

Occasionally, however, a function call returns a *function*. For example, if we look at `?scales::label_percent`, we can scroll down to

```
Value:

     All 'label_()' functions return a "labelling" function, i.e. a
     function that takes a vector 'x' and returns a character vector of
     'length(x)' giving a label for each input value.
```

Let's look at it step-by-step:

```r
fun <- scales::label_percent()
fun
# function (x) 
# {
#     number(x, accuracy = accuracy, scale = scale, prefix = prefix, 
#         suffix = suffix, big.mark = big.mark, decimal.mark = decimal.mark, 
#         style_positive = style_positive, style_negative = style_negative, 
#         scale_cut = scale_cut, trim = trim, ...)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x00000168ee5440e8>
# <environment: 0x00000168ee5501b8>
fun(0.35)
# [1] "35%"
```

The first call to `scales::label_percent()` returned a function. We can then use that function with as many arguments as we want.

If you don't want to store the returned function in a variable like `fun`, you can use it immediately by following the first set of `()`s with another set of parens.

```r
scales::label_percent()(0.35)
# [1] "35%"
```

---

A related question is *"why would you want a function to return another function?"* There are many stylistic reasons, but in the case of `scales::label_*`, they are designed to be used in places where the option needs to be expressed as a function, not as a static value. For example, it can be used in ggplot code: axis ticks are often placed conveniently with simple heuristics to determine the count, locations, and rendering of the ticks marks. While one can use `ggplot2::scale_*_manual(values = ...)` to manually control how many, where, and what they look like, it is often more convenient to not care a priori how many or where, and in cases where faceting is used, it can vary per faceting variable(s), so not something one can easily assign in a static variable. In those cases, it is often better to assign a function that is given some simple parameters (such as the min/max of the axis), and the function returns something meaningful.

Why can't we just pass it `scales::label_percent`? (Good question.) Even though you're using the default values in your call here, one might want to change any or all of the controllable things, such as:

- `suffix=` defaults to `"%"`, but perhaps you want a space as in `" %"`?
- `decimal.mark=` defaults to `"."`, but maybe your locale prefers commas?

While it is feasible to have multiple functions for all of the combinations of these options, it is generally easier in the long run to provide a "template function" for creating the function, such as

```r
fun <- scales::label_percent(accuracy = 0.01, suffix = " %", decimal.mark = ",")
fun(0.353)
# [1] "35,30 %"
scales::label_percent(accuracy = 0.01, suffix = " %", decimal.mark = ",")(0.353)
# [1] "35,30 %"
```

Comment: Once again fantastic answer!

Comment: That is a rediculously great answer.  Have you written any R books?  If not, please do.  If you ever visit Miami dinner is on me.

Answer (score 1):

An [*Expression*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Expressions) followed by an argument list in round parentheses (`(` / `)`) is called a [*Function Call*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Function-calls-_0028expressions_0029) in R.

There's no need to have a special name for two function calls in a row. They're still just function calls.

Comment: Thank you @jörg.  My confusion is not with nested function calls. Rather it is two sets of adjacent parentheses without an infix operator.  Make sense?

Comment: I don't understand. There are no nested function calls here.

Answer (score 1):

If we run a function and the value returned by the function is itself a function then we could call one that too.

For example, we first run `f` using `f()` assigning the return value to `g` but the return value is itself a function so `g` is a function -- it is the function `function() 3` -- and we can run that too.

```
# f is a function which returns a function
f <- function() function() 3  

g <- f()  # this runs f which returns `function() 3`
g()  # thus g is a function so we can call it
## [1] 3
```

Now putting that all together we can write it in one line as

```
f()()
## [1] 3
```

As seen there is only one meaning for () and the fact that there were two together was simply because we were calling the result of a call.